# Lots of invalid token errors C#

Tags: c#, token

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to start off the begging with some questions. It was going very well til I got to the bottom and it gave me a couple errors about invalid tokens. please read these lines and tell me whats wrong

```
using System;

namespace CheckIfOver18
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Start:
            Console.WriteLine("How old are you? \n");
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int yes = y;
            if (age < 18)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This game contains dismemberment and violence between victional characters, please get your parents or guardians to answer the next question.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n This game contains dismemberment and violence between victional characters, do you allow your child to play this game? Please type y for yes or n for no");
            Console.ReadKey(yes);
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for letting your child play this game, <press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
            else Console.WriteLine ("Sorry your child is not able to play this game");
        goto Start;
            if (age > 18){
                Console.WriteLine("<Press any key to continue");
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Im new so if you can tell me what to do with direct words that would be nice

Comment: what do you mean by `int yes = y;` ? what is y? Also are you sure you really want to use `goto` ?

Comment: Im trying to get them to type y for yes or n for no

Comment: there is not type y in C#

Answer (score 1):

This part

```
else Console.WriteLine ("Sorry your child is not able to play this game");
    goto Start; //maybe without this line
        if (age > 18){
            Console.WriteLine("<Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

should not be where it is right now as one line above `else` there's a closing bracket from the `Main` method so this code is outside it and it cannot be there. Probably it should be after the first condition that checks for age < 18.

Also there's a problem with `yes = y` and passing `yes` to the `Console.ReadKey` which does not take any parameters.

You can easily rewrite this code to get rid of `goto` as it is not needed in such simple scenario.